# Build a dynamic block using the default attributes

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

My plugin uses a render callback function in PHP, to display the content of a block.
The block only stores the attributes that differ from the default values.

Is there a way to pass those default values into the render callback function in PHP?

I was thinking about putting a nonsense default value to one of the attributes, so if the edit function gets called for the first time it can overwrite them and give all of the attributes a default value.

But this seems to me rather hacky, is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, and what I did is to define the attribute inside PHP and use `wp_localize_script` to pass down the array.

Then you can pass in the variable in `render_callback` using `use ($var)`

For example:

```php
$js = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js';
$css= get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css';

$default_attributes = [
  'alignment' => [ 'type' => 'string', 'default' => 'left' ],
  'iconPosition' => [ 'type' => 'string', 'default' => 'left' ],

  'textColor' => [ 'type' => 'string', 'default' => 'var(--text)' ],
  'bgColor' => [ 'type' => 'string', 'default' => 'var(--textInvert)' ],
];


wp_register_script( 'my-block', $dist . '/my-block.js', [ 'wp-blocks', 'wp-dom' ] , null, true );
wp_register_style( 'my-block', $dist . '/my-block.css', [ 'wp-edit-blocks' ] );

wp_localize_script( 'my-block', 'myBlockLocalize', [ 'attributes' => $default_attributes ] );

register_block_type( 'my/block', [
  'editor_style' => 'my-block',
  'editor_script' => 'my-block',
  'render_callback' => function( $atts, $inner_blocks = null ) use ( $default_attributes ) {
      $default_values = array_map( function( $a ) {
        return $a['default'] ?? '';
      }, $default_attributes );

      $atts = wp_parse_args( $atts, $default_values );

      ob_start();
      // output the HTML here, I believe you can use get_template_parts()
      return ob_get_clean();
    }
] );
```

In your JS:

```js
...

registerBlockType( 'my/block', {
  title: 'My Block',
  icon: 'id',
  category: 'layout',
  example: {},
  attributes: myBlockLocalize.attributes,
  
  // ...

} );

...
```